# Have the Spark GUI provide domain names for cluster nodes

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark cluster with multiple nodes. When I click on a worker or application the link points to the private IP of the related machine, which goes nowhere. I have to manually copy the link and edit it to have the public domain or IP of the machine so that I can actually view the content of the link.

I have Ambari running a NiFi as well, but by providing the name resolution between private IP and domain name in the hosts file Ambari is able to provide me with public links that work based on the domain name associated to the private IP address.

Is there a way to setup spark to provide the proper links similar to how Ambari handles this?